# gradle: Error running 'Unnamed': No task to execute is specified

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea

I got an Android app for further development as a zip file. I unzipped and opened this in **Jetbrains IDEA File> Open (Folder Address).**

IDEA immediately realized that it was an android app.

This did not start.

Later I copied the gradle to **C: \ Gradle and added it to the path (works well, see gradle -v in the screenshot).**

But I still get errors below. How you could help. Thanks.

```
10:21   Frameworks Detected
            Android framework is detected.
            Configure
10:22   All files are up-to-date
10:22   Error running 'build': Module 'monkey' is not backed by gradle
10:23   All files are up-to-date
10:23   Error running 'build (1)': No jdk for module 'monkey-tree-app'
10:23   All files are up-to-date
10:23   Error running 'build': Module 'monkey-tree-app' is not backed by gradle
10:24   All files are up-to-date
10:24   Error running 'build': No jdk for module 'monkey-tree-app'
10:30   Error running 'Unnamed': No task to execute is specified
10:56   Error running 'Unnamed (1)': No task to execute is specified
```

[image]

Comment: share your gradle file here

Comment: <pre>
```// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
Import Project
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
</pre>```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sl5net/3c9815272d8495097b03025211331304 named build.gradle

Comment: It looks like the project is not fully imported as a Gradle project in IDE. Try to open project via File | New | Project from existing sources pointing to the main build.gradle file and let the IDE re-created the project configuration.

Comment: thanks.    i did: 1) right click "build.gradle" > build module ... 2) autoimort YES 3) read msg: "All files are up-to-date" 4) right click "build.gradle" > run build 5) read: "Error running 'build': No jdk for module'  hmmm